# How to count the number of times the program is called - in linux c

Tags: linux

I have a variable in a program to store how many times that program is called/executed.

Every time, the program or application is called, the variable will be displayed.

How to do it in Linux C.

Regards,
Arun AC

Comment: Save it in external file, when you want to display, read from that file

Comment: You can't reliably store the value in the program itself.  You *can* write a shell script, that 1) updates an external "counter file", then 2) invokes the program itself.

Comment: If you really have to, declare a static string with a pattern that will contain your count, then read and write that string. RSS uses a similar scheme to read revision string. Search for a copy of rcsutils.c . Howver, having said that, why bother, when you can use one of the techniques provided above.

Comment: Maybe you also want to create a wrapper script and make it the same name and path as the original program and move the original program to a different location. This way you won't lose any count if the program is called by some other script.